# Postfix: 550 5.7.1 You're not in the list of allowed users to send e-mails to this domain - stay out

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I just setup a postfix mail, currently I can send/receive email internal, but I cannot receive email from external domain like gmail, I got an error:
550 5.7.1 You're not in the list of allowed users to send e-mails to this domain - stay out!

I think postfix by default limited external domain, please advise me how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned error is related to outgoing email, not the inbound one.
`550 5.7.1` basically means that server IP address is blacklisted due to spamming or domain settings do not meet Google's requirements. The domain may be checked at https://mxtoolbox.com/domain/ to get the list of all issues.

As to my knowledge, Postfix does not impose some heavy restrictions in the default configuration. Even if so, you will get a clear message in mail log regarding the config limitations.
Usually, The issues are caused by ISP blocking the outgoing mail or specific policies by large mail providers such as Google.

Comment: I used gmail and other mail server sent to Postfix mail server, then got a same error. Check with mxtoolbox, I found out our domain have no DMARC record, will try to fix it and resend.